# How to implement CalenderView in Android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am new at android this, so this might sound a bit confusing..

i am making an app that requires to have calendars showing events in week, day and month views (like google calendar). I have implemented this is a testing version but i want to change the implementation to make it more flexible. currently the event are stored in database and are edited and used in various activities in the app. Can i have android manage the events in it's calendar? but i would still need to be able to manipulate it from the app and store extra info other than the time and date and description. These extra info will be used for calculations. We also need to have a calendar in the app. Can we retrieve the events specific to the app for doing all this?

Comment: *"Can i have android manage the events in it's calendar?"* I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: Currently the events stored in database. I want to have alarms remainders on these events and also sync with android (these are not included in the test app). Doing all this in the present implementation seems like a daunting task. I have been reading about CalendarContract. Is it possible to have android manage my events, set reminders, sync and other stuff while i am still able to retrieve, edit them from the app and also set extra properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/) might be of help.